# Создается два экземпляра NotificationListenerService. Как их можно использовать в DependencyInjection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-notification, prism

Есть приложение со встроенным сервисом прослушки уведомлений. Т.к я использую prism, мне необходимо регистрировать этот сервис, который наследуется от моего интерфейса `INotificationListenerService`. При регистрации я обращаюсь к свойству `Current`, (т.к. сервис работает даже после закрытия приложения). Если экземпляр отсутствует, возвращается новый. Но после регистрации самостоятельно создается другой экземпляр сервиса, который уже никак не регистрируется в контейнере. И этот второй экземпляр реагирует на появление уведомлений, но на его события уже никак нельзя подписаться.

Вопрос: каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы в контейнер попадал именно второй экземпляр, они каким-либо образом объединялись ил подменяли друг-друга?

**Регистрация:**

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<INotificationListenerService>(NotificationListenerService.Current);
```

**Интерфейс**:

```
public interface INotificationListenerService
{
    bool IsListenerConnected { get; }

    public event EventHandler<bool> ConnectionStateChanged;

    public event EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs> NotificationPosted;
}
```

**Класс:**

```
[Service(Label = "Ardulens Notification listener service", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE", Exported =true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" })]
public class NotificationListenerService : Android.Service.Notification.NotificationListenerService, INotificationListenerService
{
    public event EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs> NotificationPosted;
    public event EventHandler<bool> ConnectionStateChanged;

    private static NotificationListenerService current;
    public static NotificationListenerService Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (current == null)
            {
                current = new NotificationListenerService();
            }
            return current;
        }
        private set => current = value;
    }

    public bool IsListenerConnected { get; private set; }
    public override void OnListenerConnected()
    {
        base.OnListenerConnected();
        IsListenerConnected = true;
        ConnectionStateChanged?.Invoke(this, IsListenerConnected);
    }

    public override void OnListenerDisconnected()
    {
        base.OnListenerDisconnected();
        IsListenerConnected = false;
        ConnectionStateChanged?.Invoke(this, IsListenerConnected);
    }

    public NotificationListenerService()
    {
        if(current == null)
            Current = this;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    public override void OnNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
         NotificationPosted?.Invoke(this, new NotificationEventArgs(sbn));
         var text = sbn.Notification.Extras.GetCharSequence(Notification.ExtraText);
         var title = sbn.Notification.Extras.GetCharSequence(Notification.ExtraTitle);
         //Log.Debug(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.Id + "t" + sbn.Notification.TickerText + "t" + sbn.PackageName);
         Debug.WriteLine("\ntext: " + text + " title: " + title + "\n");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Странный у вас сервис... Во первых, статика, зачем она? Допустим `static bool IsChecked { get; }`, ну это прям костыль... Далее, `current = new NotificationListenerService();` - так вы берете ответственность за создание на себя, а не отдаете контейнеру, у вас вообще не должно быть в проекте `= new()`! Также вы делаете так называемый "синглтон". который также должен делать контейнер, а не вы. То есть, у вас должно быть просто `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<INotificationListenerService, NotificationListenerService>();`.

Comment: Is checked - это не используется. Я забыл его убрать, после того, как эксперементировал ). Я использую new(), т.к. приложение продолжает работать в фоне, и если при каждом открытии его регистрировать синглтоном, то создается несколько объектов. Допустимо ли регистрировать таким образом: 
    `if(NotificationListenerService.Current == null) containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<INotificationListenerService, NotificationListenerService>();` ?

Comment: "работает в фоне" - это баг или фича? Если баг, то наверно стоит найти решение. Если фича, то я вряд ли вам чем-либо помогу, ибо не знаю, как правильно реализовать подобное в мобильной сфере. В любом случае, у вас не должно быть несколько копий, если тип зарегистрирован как синглтон. Если у вас это не так, то значит вы что-то делаете не то.

Comment: По поводу `if(NotificationListenerService...)` - я не пойму смысл этого, как и вы походу не поймете смысл контейнеров. Контейнер, это место, где при иниуилизации приложения регистрируются все типы, эти типы инициализируются тогда, когда это надо, по первому требованию, контейнер не должен знать "если такой-то тип уже кем был инициализирован, то не регистрировать его", ибо тогда у вас будет ошибка в тех местах, где вы используете интерфейс, который не зарегистрирован в контейнере. Повторю еще раз, вы не должны брать на себя ответственность за создание объекта, это обязанность контейнера!

Comment: Приложение продолжает работать как раз таки из-за NotificationListener. Он не позволяет приложению остановиться. Я читал про этот косяк, и исправить его  (вроде как) нельзя. Я понимаю, для чего нужны контейнеры, но не знаю, как их использовать в моем случае.

Comment: `Я читал про этот косяк, и исправить его (вроде как) нельзя.` - я не думаю, что это "косяк", наверно его надо остановить, задиспоузить, удалить перед закрытием? Я бы на вашем месте сделал бы так: Класс, который реализует `NotificationListenerService` андройда, он приватный (нефиг ему на ружу лезть). Далее класс сервиса, он вызывает методы "нотификатора", подписывается на что надо и отдает наружу нужные органы управления через интерфейс, сам нотификатор пусть в конструкторе сервиса инициализируется.

Comment: Далее простая регистрация как синглтон `.RegisterSingleton<интефрейс, сервис>();`, ну и первом вызове этого интерфейса, у вас подтянется "нотификатор". Ну и далее, там где регистрируете типы, переопределяете `OnExit`, берете из контейнера интерфейс, и диспоузите его (наверно внутренний метод службы для этого надо). Что-то по типу `protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e) { Container.Resolve<интерфейс>().Stop(); }`. И да, все обращение только через интерфейс, никак иначе, только контейнер, только DI...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение: создал дополнительный класс `NLService`, который наследуется от этого интерфейса и содержит в себе объект `NotificationListenerService`. В сам `NotificationListenerService` добавил событие, возникающее при создании класса. В NLService подписался на это событие сохранил новый объект.

Вот, что получилось:

```
public class NLService : INotificationListenerService
{
    private NotificationListenerService _nlistener; //объект слушателя

    public event EventHandler<bool> ConnectionStateChanged;
    public event EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs> NotificationPosted;

    private static NLService _current;
    public static NLService Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current == null)
                _current = new();
            return _current;
        }
        private set => _current = value;
    }

    public bool IsListenerConnected
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nlistener != null)
                return _nlistener.IsListenerConnected;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public NLService()
    {
        NotificationListenerService.NewInstanceCreated += OnNewInstanceCreated;
    }

    private void OnNewInstanceCreated(object sender, NotificationListenerService e)
    {
        _nlistener = e;
        _nlistener.ConnectionStateChanged += (o, e) => ConnectionStateChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        _nlistener.NotificationPosted += (o, e) => NotificationPosted?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}


[Service(Label = "Ardulens Notification listener service", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE", Exported =true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" })]
class NotificationListenerService : Android.Service.Notification.NotificationListenerService
{
    public event EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs> NotificationPosted;
    public event EventHandler<bool> ConnectionStateChanged;

    public static event EventHandler<NotificationListenerService> NewInstanceCreated;

    public bool IsListenerConnected { get; private set; }
    public override void OnListenerConnected()
    {
        base.OnListenerConnected();
        IsListenerConnected = true;
        ConnectionStateChanged?.Invoke(this, IsListenerConnected);
    }

    public override void OnListenerDisconnected()
    {
        base.OnListenerDisconnected();
        IsListenerConnected = false;
        ConnectionStateChanged?.Invoke(this, IsListenerConnected);
    }

    public NotificationListenerService()
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        NewInstanceCreated?.Invoke(this, this);
    }

    public override void OnNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
            NotificationPosted?.Invoke(this, new NotificationEventArgs(sbn));
            var text = sbn.Notification.Extras.GetCharSequence(Notification.ExtraText);
            var title = sbn.Notification.Extras.GetCharSequence(Notification.ExtraTitle);
            //Log.Debug(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.Id + "t" + sbn.Notification.TickerText + "t" + sbn.PackageName);
            Debug.WriteLine("\ntext: " + text + " title: " + title + "\n");
       
    }
}
```

И при регистрации передаю экземпляр NLService:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<INotificationListenerService>(NLService.Current);
```